# SVG Zoom Performace Issues with javascript on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm currently tring to implement zoom on pdf pages which are in a svg format.

I'm modifying the viewbox so as to allow zoom. While this works quite well on the desktop i'm having huge performance issues on the iPad.

Does anyone know how to implement this another way than by modifying the viewbox ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

Outer `<svg>` elements have [currentScale and currentTranslate](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#InterfaceSVGSVGElement) properties that are designed to allow zoom/pan to be implemented.

Comment: Hey Robert, would you say this suggestion is still valid as of 2018?

Comment: Those properties are still present but I think they only work on standalone SVG documents.

Comment: I see ty, i am using viewBox for panzoom here - morphistic.app. But i see slight jitters with current implementation and wonder if there is a faster methods

Comment: It's always tradeoff between jitter and sharpness, there's no implementation that can do both.

Comment: Cool ty, i am not too worried as modern devices are quite fast, was just wondering if there were some hidden gems;)